# GetDelegatedResource return empty result

Tags: tron

I want to implement [GetDelegatedResource](https://developers.tron.network/reference/getdelegatedresource) tron API function. But I get empty result.

I post this data

```
{
"fromAddress": "TRYQ8gSqk8BY6kqJ868UCnDqPC7LtAgaaA",
"toAddress": "TLEjNeLN1wMKiF7buc45wZzMsbk6dMUMDY",
"visible": true
}
```

to url `https://nile.trongrid.io/wallet/getdelegatedresource`

What do I do wrong?